# Using startTrackPage in Application Insights

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-application-insights

I have recently been messing around with Application Insights and have been having a problem with getting the JavaScript API to work.  In the default script that you are supposed to add to your page, they use the function trackPageView().  This seems to works, but I had also wanted to gather information about how long a user stayed on the page.  I found the startTrackPage() and stopTrackPage() functions and tried to use those to get the information, but I always receive an error from startTrackPage().

*Uncaught TypeError: appInsights.startTrackPage is not a function(anonymous function)*

I have stepped through the code and the function does not seem to be created at the point I am calling it.  trackPageView() is already defined though.  I tried calling the function after the document loaded as well and that still failed.  However, I can call it from the developer console once the page loads.

[Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-custom-events-metrics-api/#page-views) is where I found the information about startTrackPage() and stopTrackPage() originally.  Other than that I have just been perusing around to see if anyone else has encountered this.

I appreciate the help.

Default code from App Insight:

```js
window.appInsights = appInsights;
appInsights.startPageView();
```

What I have tried:

```js
window.appInsights = appInsights;
appInsights.startTrackPage();

window.onunload = function () {
  appInsights.stopTrackPage();
};
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? This will better help us isolate the problem.

Comment: Don't know that it will help, but it's added.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: unfortunately there's currently no way to use appInsights.startTrackPage() in the way you intend reliably.

Long answer: The reason is that startTrackPage() method is only defined in the JS that is downloaded from CDN, so until it is downloaded it is not defined.
What you could do it something like:

```
appInsights.queue.push(function(){appInsights.startTrackPage();})
```

however this would not produce correct measurement, because tracking won't start right away.
So your best approach would be record start time manually, however even that you cannot do reliably. First of all you absolutely don't want to use onunload event as at this point it will be too late for Application Insights SDK to send the data so it will most likely get lost. Using onbeforeunload and flush() will help with this problem a little bit:

```
var pageStart =  +new Date;
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
  appInsights.trackMetric("timeOnPage", (+new Date)-pageStart);
  appInsights.flush();
});
```

However even when using onbeforeunload you are looking at high number of potential data losses - you cannot guarantee that ajax request to send data to Application Insights will complete before page navigates away and connection is interrupted. In my testing with IE was getting about 50% of losses.